# jython 2.7.2 getting syntax error when adding datatype to parameter

Tags: jython

using this:
`def func(self, d:str): pass`

results in this error:

SyntaxError: mismatched input ':' expecting RPAREN

how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. Jython 2.7.2 uses python 2.7. this syntax above is python 3+ syntax. so it doesn't work.